# SAPUI5 - OData is not defined

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying send some data to sap gateway service.
I am using this [example](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/02/05/simple-exercise-on-odata-and-sap-ui5-application-for-the-basic-crud-operation/) the method "save", but when I try do it in my code I get an error "OData is not defined"

Below is the method when I try do it.

```
        handleConfirmationMessageBoxPress: function(oEvent) {
        var bCompact = !!this.getView().$().closest(".sapUiSizeCompact").length;
        MessageBox.confirm(
            "Deseja confirmar a transferência?", {
                icon: sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.SUCCESS,
                title: "Confirmar",
                actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.CANCEL],
                onClose: function(oAction) {
                    if (oAction == "OK") {
                        var oParameters = {};
                        oParameters.loginfrom = this.getView().byId("multiInput").getValue();
                        oParameters.loginfrom = this.getView().byId("loginPara").getValue();
                        oParameters.loginfrom = this.getView().byId("datade").getValue();
                        oParameters.loginfrom = this.getView().byId("datapara").getValue();

                        OData.request({
                            requestUri : "http://<host name>:<port no>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_EMP_SRV/EmployeeSet",
                            method : "GET",
                            headers : {...}
                                        },
                                        function(data, response) {
                                                 ...
                                                    var oHeaders = {
                                         ... };
                            OData.request({
                                                    requestUri : "http://<host name>:<port no>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_EMP_SRV/EmployeeSet",
                                                    method : "POST",
                                                    headers : oHeaders,
                                                    data:oParameters
                                        },
                                                    function(data,request) {
                                                    MessageToast.show("Transferência realizada!");       
                                                    location.reload(true);
                                        },          function(err) {
                                                    MessageToast.show("A transferência falhou!");
                                        });
                            }, function(err) {
                                                    var request = err.request;
                                                    var response = err.response;
                                                    alert("Error in Get — Request " + request + " Response " + response);
                                        });  


                    } else {
                        ...
```

Comment: X is not defined usually means that a given variable X is still undefined. You have to properly initialize your OData variable. Sadly, after reading your example, I do not know what the author was thinking.. maybe OData is some global var in his example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use the OData global object from the datajs library. This library is indeed shipped with OpenUI5, but IMO you should not use it directly (but use the methods of the [OData model](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html); there is no real guarantee that UI5 will continue shipping this third-party library in the future).

You are most likely getting the error because the library was not yet loaded by UI5. Libraries are generally lazily loaded by UI5, so you will have to request that UI5 loads it for you (in the tutorial that you have linked, it was loaded behind the scenes by the OData model). To do this, you can either use [jQuery.sap.require](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.require) (jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.datajs")) or list the dependency inside your [sap.ui.define](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define) call at the beginning of the controller (e.g. `sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/thirdparty/datajs'], function(datajs){...})`).

Later edit: you can also use the `jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.odata.datajs");` call, but the module was moved from there and it would effectively redirect you to the new location.

Comment: I download the datajs-1.0.1.min.js, put in my directory and include in my index.html, so it works.
Does it correct?

Comment: You do not need to download the datajs separately. As I have mentioned in the answer, "This library **is shipped** with OpenUI5". This means that UI5 has the library inside it by default, but it loads it only when it needs it or you request it. To request it, you can use the require / define calls as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very old example, and the used old techniques.
You should add this line to your code:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.odata.datajs");
```

This should solve your oData is undefined problem.
In general you should read newer examples where the read() function of the odata model is used.

Comment: I donwload the datajs-1.0.1.min.js, put in my directory and include in my index.html, so it works.
Does it correct?